# Type casting pointer when writing to binary file in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, binaryfiles, typecasting-operator

Today in CS 111 class my instructor ended with a 'brief' look at writing structures to binary files. I say brief because he just included it as a kind of aside, saying it would not be on the final. Problem is, I don't fully understand what's going on in the program example and it is bothering me. Hopefully somebody will take the time to explain it to me. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct PayStub
{
    int id_num;
    bool overtime;
    float hourly_rate;
};

int main()
{
    PayStub info = {1234, false, 15.45};

    ofstream data_store;

    data_store.open("test.cs111", ios::binary);

    char *raw_data = (char*)&info;
    data_store.write(raw_data, sizeof(PayStub));

    data_store.close();

    return 0;

}
```

I don't understand what is going on specifically in the statement `char *raw_data = (char*)&info;` and why it is necessary. I understand a pointer to a char is being declared and initialized, but what exactly is it being initialized to, and how is that being used in the next line?
I hope this isn't a stupid question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [address_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of)

Comment: It *reads* `info` content memory as byte array, which leads to implementation specific value with padding and endianness, floating point representation...

Comment: "brief, and non-portable" :p

Comment: In C++, you would write this code as: `auto* raw_data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::addressof(info));`

Comment: It is a pointer to the first byte of `info`

Comment: and it's an inefficiently packed `struct`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *raw_data = (char*)&info;` after this line, raw_data will point to the address of the first byte of `info`.

With `data_store.write(raw_data, sizeof(PayStub));` we ask data_store to write  to the file the contents in memory that start at `raw_data` and end at `raw_data + sizeof(PayStub))`.

In essence we find the start address and length of `PayStub` and write it to disk.

It is not a stupid question. Once you read up on pointers, everything will make sense.

Comment: It is a pointer pointing to the first char starting at the address of info- ?

Comment: Exactly. To the first byte of info.

Comment: So then when writing to file it is writing a byte at a time until it reaches the full size of the strict? Thank you very much. I will go back to reading up on pointers.

Comment: I don't know the exact implementation of `ofstream` but you can think about it like this, yes. Most probably it ends up calling [write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_%28system_call%29)

Comment: I have finished my degree, and am fully employed. I am looking at my old questions .... very grateful for the help over the years .

Answer (score 0):

Think of a [`struct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) (in plain C) to simply be a way of binding a bunch of [object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object)s together with "string".

An `int` could be represented in memory with 4 bytes. A struct composed of two `int`s would be 8 bytes, one `int` next to the other.

In your example code, `&info` returns the pointer to the beginning of the object in memory, and `(char*)&info` simply interprets as a pointer to a character instead, so it can be treated as a sequence of binary data. `sizeof` returns how much memory (in bytes) the struct takes, and with this information the structure is then written directly to a file from memory.

Keep in mind this type of data storage is absolutely *not* portable. It might vary from a 32-bit to a 64-bit computer!

Comment: _"and `(char*)&info` simply interprets as a pointer to a character instead"_ - the term "character" may be misleading to a C++ newcomer, especially in this context of binary files.


It should be emphasized that `char` is the C/C++ fundamental type that represents a single byte. Not just any "character".


Thus, commonly, arguments in the C++ standard library functions that stand for raw data block are typically typed as `char*` or `const char*`.

Comment: @kupiakos so is it writing a sequence of binary data, one char size (byte) at a time?

Comment: Yes, it's writing the raw value of the struct in memory one char size (byte) at a time.

Comment: @Sinux1 The result would be as if the binary data was written one byte at a time, but whether the data was actually copied in one way or another - that is implementation-dependent.